# Sending Data to Server when NetConnection is Available from Device IOS7

Tags: ios, objective-c, internet-connection

Hi,

In my application I have a small registration form. I want the functionality to work like following

- If the device is connected to network, data should be stored directly
  in server.
- If device is not connected to network, then it should
  store temporarily in device and when the device connects to network
  it has to store the data in online server.

Please tell if this is possible and what is the right method to do it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Yes, it's possible
- You can store whatever state you want locally and use one of the Reachability classes to see if a network connection is available and then attempt to run your network code to upload this state to the server.

Comment: can pls Elaborate your answer so then it will very user with some examples

Comment: How about trying it yourself and then coming back if you have specific problems. Stack overflow isn't a code requesting site.

Comment: @Abozern ok i will try